# SQL Query for search in a Parent Child relationship and retrieve all nodes and all their parents

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have db table with parent child relationship like:

```
ID         Name         ParentID
-------------------------------------
1         Computer          0
2         Software          1
3         Hardware          1
4         Windows           2
5         Games             0
6         Windows           5
7         Linux             5
8         3D                6
9         DirectX           8
```

I want to search on this table for word 'Windows' and I want results as below:

```
ID         Name         ParentID
-------------------------------------
1         Computer          0          <== Grandparent of 4
2         Software          1          <== Parent of 4
4         Windows           2          <== 4
5         Games             0          <== Parent of 6
6         Windows           5          <== 6
```

I mean all **parents** which has a relation with search word should be kept and the rest should be removed from records

Comment: Solutions in ASP.NET C# code is also appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx?ppud=4)

```
with C as 
(
  select T.ID, T.Name, T.ParentID
  from @T as T
  where Name = 'Windows'
  union all
  select T.ID, T.Name, T.ParentID
  from YourTable as T
    inner join C
      on T.ID = C.ParentID
)
select ID, Name, ParentID
from C
order by ID;
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75843)

Comment: Your solution is awesome, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`HierarchyId` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) and then use the `IsDescendant` of method

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE @searchId.IsDescendantOf(ID) = 1
```

This allows you to perform arbitrary recursion and/or looping. It's fast and straightforward.